# Laravel/Blade storing to the Database (Route::post)

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm having a serious issue regarding the creation of new accounts on my database, and I have no idea what is at fault here.

Routes:
[Routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wygQk.png)

View: [View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRNf7.png)

And the Controller: [AccountController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpPpw.png)

I was trying to debug it by using the dd() but as I've seen the method isn't even being called, so dd() isn't even reached. I'll also include the custom validator that I created: [Validator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe76m.png)

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, and I want to be sure I'm successfully adding to the database. Can someone find the issue?

Thanks in advance.

@Edit - Thank you so much to everyone that contributed to solving this issue, it is now working properly and saving correctly to my database! I had only to remove the Validator that I created and also to manage the variables properly in my view.blade, and that was it!

Comment: add code.. instead of image

Comment: Remove validator and check is dd() working

Comment: dd() is now working, but since I removed the validator, I had to put Request $request as a parameter in the function again, and now the $request->get is now unavailable

Comment: And sorry for the images, I thought it was easier to see everything rather than pre-selection parts of the code. It's my first time posting

Comment: When you do get it saving, you are going to need some way to associate the record with a user?

Comment: can you inspect your form on browers and show action url for me ?

Comment: Well, now I have a problem in this bit of code, since I replaced the validator with the Request $request and it's giving me an Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$account_type_id

$account->account_type_id= $request->account_type_id;
        $account->code = $request->code;
        $account->start_balance = $request->start_balance;
        $account->date = $request->date;
        $account->description = $request->description;

Comment: I can try @Truong Dang, although it might be hard since I have an error in the way

Comment: Yes @Snapey, I'm going to have the accounts associated with the user in question

Comment: See the anwser bellow, the cancel button may be is submit button... Submit button is not sobmit anythings

Comment: Go to `storage/logs/laravel.log`. Clear that file and submit to see that anything wrong ?

Comment: Do you still have `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of the controller... it looks like you changed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change **select** tag according. And keep remaining code what you have provided to me.

**From:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="account_type_id">
```

**To:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="account_type_id" name="account_type">
```

Comment: @Slifer47 Please also click on tick icon below the points section.

Comment: The `name` of the form element needs to match what you are looking for in the request object.  It was `account_type_id` but you seem to have changed the code multiple times since then.

Comment: It did help, that was the issue! Seriously thank you to everyone, it is now saving and working properly! What an awesome community! I'll make sure to edit my question with the answer, and I already ticked the answer ^^

Answer (score 1):

You did not say what is actually wrong, but it seems to me that your button to store the form is missing `type='submit'` although I see you have that on your cancel button.

Maybe pressing cancel will save the data!

Comment: That right ! Cancel button actualy submit button... :D

Comment: Although that is a good observation, I can assure you that the submit button works fine, and it's still reproducing the same error that I mentioned in the comments xD